# Making a movieclip appear when mousing-over a button

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to create a disclaimer link that, when moused-over, a movie clip (disclaimer window) will show-up on the swf. How do I do this in AS3, please?

I'm new, and I've only gotten this far:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,showOptions);
function showOptions (e: MouseEvent): void {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your disclaimer window movieclip dynamically from your library like so:

```
function showOptions(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var disclaimer:MovieClip = new disclaimerMC();
    disclaimer.name = "disclaimer"; //give disclaimer name in case used later
    disclaimer.x = 100; //set coordinates of movieclip
    disclaimer.y = 100;
    this.addChild(disclaimer); //add the disclaimer to the screen
}
```

Make sure that you go to your disclaimer movieclip in the library, right-click it, go to properties / linkage, and change the `Class` field. In my example, I changed the `Class` field to `disclaimerMC`.

It might also be nice to let Flash know which movieclips the EventListener should apply to. The way your code is now, mousing over anything would call `showOptions`. As you probably don't want that, you can say

```
disclaimerLink.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,showOptions);
```

So then, only when you mouse over `disclaimerLink` will `disclaimer` show.

---

Alternatively, if the disclaimer window will always appear and disappear in the same place, it is quicker to change its transparency value. Your `MOUSE_OVER` and `MOUSE_OUT` functions can call `disclaimer.alpha=100;` and `disclaimer.alpha=0;`, respectively.

Comment: I'm new to the site - how do I post my new code? I did what you recommended and, while I'm not getting compiler errors anymore (yay!), I'm also not getting any mouse events. Nothing happens when I mouse over my disclaimerButton. Trying to figure out how to share my code with you... :)

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: 

Symbol 'disclaimerButton', Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 4 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addEventListener through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: It finally worked! The thing is that I had to move "var disclaimer..." up on top, otherwise I had to redefine it in my function hideOptions.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Great! Awesome that you got that last part, no problem at all.